# How I can group by and count in PostgreSQL to prevent empty cells in result

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the table in PostgreSQL DB

[image]

Need to calculate SUM of counts for each `event_type` (example for 4 and 1)
When I use query like this

```
SELECT account_id, date,
  CASE
    WHEN event_type = 1 THEN SUM(count)
    ELSE null
  END AS shows,
  CASE
    WHEN event_type = 4 THEN SUM(count)
    ELSE null
  END AS clicks
FROM widgetstatdaily WHERE account_id = 272 AND event_type = 1 OR event_type = 4 GROUP BY account_id, date, event_type ORDER BY date
```

I receive this table

[image]

With `<null>` fields. It's because I have `event_type` in select and I need to `GROUP BY` on it.

How I can make query to receive grouped by account_id and date result without null's in cells? Like (first row)

```
272   2018-03-28 00:00:00.000000    57    2
```

May be I can group it after receiving result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try its

```
SELECT account_id, date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN event_type = 1 THEN count  else 0 END) as shows,
       SUM(CASE WHEN event_type = 4 THEN count  else 0 END) as clicks
FROM widgetstatdaily
WHERE account_id = 272 AND
      event_type IN (1, 4)
GROUP BY account_id, date
ORDER BY date;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need conditional aggregation and some other fixes.  Try this:

```
SELECT account_id, date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN event_type = 1 THEN count END) as shows,
       SUM(CASE WHEN event_type = 4 THEN count END) as clicks
FROM widgetstatdaily
WHERE account_id = 272 AND
      event_type IN (1, 4)
GROUP BY account_id, date
ORDER BY date;
```

Notes:

- The `CASE` expression should be an argument to the `SUM()`.
- The `ELSE NULL` is redundant.  The default without an `ELSE` is `NULL`.
- The logic in the `WHERE` clause is probably not what you intend.  That is fixed using `IN`.

Comment: Unreal Gordon.  Our answers were even almost formatted the same way.  You must get carpal tunnel regularly :-)